# Why are two additional <p> elements being created in between my content?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I set up a basic php file for my WordPress theme:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class = "content">
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
  <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no pages found.' ); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

When I ran my theme and opened up inspect element, it said that *there were two additional paragraph elements* on top and below my paragraph element containing the content (`<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>`).

It looked like this in the inspector:

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<p></p>
<p>Content</p>
<p></p>
```

Why is it doing this?

***Edit:*** Found a "solution": Although it wont remove the paragraph elements, it will make them invisible in case you want to adjust the padding, margin, or any other attribute of your content:

```
.content p:first-child { /*...in my case, my content paragraph is in a 'content' div...*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /*...or any other attribute...*/
}

.content p:last-child {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: the inspector shows dynamically generated html, so get sure it's actual http output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have extra paragraph from [wpauto](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop).

Try adding this to functions.php:

`remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');`

Answer (score 0):

WordPress replaces new lines with paragraphs in post content.

You have additional start and end p tags output by `the_content();`

Answer (score 0):

Remove unwanted `<p>` tag.

```
/**
 * Remove empty <p> tag.
 * 
 * @param type $content
 * @return type
 */
function pd_remove_unwanted_p($content){
    $content = force_balance_tags( $content );
    $content = preg_replace( '#<p>\s*+(<br\s*/*>)?\s*</p>#i', '', $content );
    $content = preg_replace( '~\s?<p>(\s|&nbsp;)+</p>\s?~', '', $content );
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'pd_remove_unwanted_p', 20, 1);
```

Just put above code in your active theme `functions.php`.